# LBFGS -- Incomplete Convergence due to BadIntpln

Tags: molecular-dynamics, geometry-optimization, numerical-convergence, optimization, tinker

I am doing energy minimization of a molecular system in TINKER. While doing so, I am getting the error in the title of this question. What might be my problem?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! We hope to see much more of you in the future. How did you find us? It looks like that error message [only appears in one other place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0MEp.png) on the world wide web, and it was 15 years ago. It would be nice for the solution to this problem to be answered here on MMSE where it will be easily searchable.

Comment: I have no familiarity at all with TINKER personally, but I suspect the question would be easier to answer if you provided details of what you are doing, e.g. in the form of an input file.